# Does a CakePHP User Session retain on server if set via AJAX call from phonegap?

Tags: php, ajax, session, cakephp, cordova

I'm developing my first phonegap application that is using CakePHP (Croogo) backend.
If I'm sending my username and password via AJAX from phonegap to CakePHP, I can successfully log in with CakePHP's $this->Auth->login(). The User session is generated correctly, I can get back the user data from CakePHP by reading $this->Session->read('User') right after login.
But if I make another AJAX call from my phonegap app to get that User Session, I dont get the value.

So far I thought that if I set a session on server side, it is readable later (from the same browser session), because the browser has the appropriate cookies set.

Now I'm confused, if CakePHP creates a new session for every AJAX call?

```
public function ajax_login_from_phonegap($user) {
  [...]
  if ($this->Auth->login($user)) {
    $response["user"] = $user;
    $response["msg"] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
    //here I got the correct value!
    return $response;
  }
  [...]
}  

public function another_action_from_phonegap() {
  echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
  // here I have null
}
```

Am I just missing something or am I thinking wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help!
(Configure::version() = '2.5.5')

Comment: Its like every time you are making a API call to the server in which application is run in php. So you just have to generate a key send them every time after login while you send request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be more general than related to CakePHP. When you are logged in, does your phonegapp app keep the session cookie? And do you send that cookie on the second AJAX call?
Sessions works because the client keep track of a cookie containing its session ID and then send it everytime a request is made, this way the server can identify the session and associated it with the corresponding session.

Comment: Hi Chadrien, thanks for your answer. I cannot get phonegap to store the cookies so far, so now I am sending the session id back to phonegap in my json response, and I send it along with each AJAX call, but I cannot connect to the existing session, I always get a new session id from cake. I'm trying $this->Session->id($sessionid_got_from_phonegap) but no avail...

Comment: Finally, I managed to figure out that my login is working in its original version. The problem is that Ripple cannot receive the cookie, I got a working solution when running the app on a device.

Your answer however helped me to get into it, so I give it a check. :) 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have set `$this->Session->('User')` but you are trying to read `$this->Session->('Auth.user.username')`.

Comment: CakePHP sets the session automatically after successful $this->Auth->login(). The generated user session has many fields, like username, id, email, etc.

Comment: Oops. You're correct. I was thinking of `$this->Auth->('user')`.